# About video/webm and mp4

Tags: javascript, html, mp4, webm

Hope there hadn't any question same as mine.

I tried to write some share screen and screen record. For that I found others code to study.
In the code, it used the video filename extension is .webm.  I tried to change it to .mp4 but failed.

I thought that `video/webm` and `video/mp4` were both valid. But not know why, when I changed  filename extension, it got worse.

Is there anything wrong I didn't find? I had tried some keywords to search (for example, video/webm mp4) but had no result. I would like to know if my keyword direction is wrong?

Thankyou.

The following is part of the code:

```
btnPlay.onclick = () => {
    var blob = new Blob(buffer, { type: 'video/webm' })
    recvideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    recvideo.srcObject = null
    recvideo.controls = true
    recvideo.play()
}

// download record
btnDownload.onclick = () => {
    var blob = new Blob(buffer, { type: 'video/webm' })
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    var a = document.createElement('a')

    a.href = url
    a.style.display = 'none'
    a.download = 'video.webm'
    a.click()
}
```

In the code, I only changed `webm` to `mp4`.

The code source: https://ithelp.ithome.com.tw/articles/10273368?sc=iThomeR

Comment: webm is a different container format to mp4 (specifically it's matroska) - you can't just change the file extension to make it an mp4. Wherever your `buffer` comes from would need to output an mp4 if that's the format you want.

Comment: This is just playing or downloading a video, you can't just change the type of the video by changing it there, you need to record it with the right format to begin with.

Comment: @Luke Briggs, Karl-Johan Sjögren: In this way, I thought too simple at first. Thanks a lot for your reply! Maybe I should consider other ways.

Comment: @Sojona108 WebM uses the VP9 codec which is a free video format but H264 codec encoding is usually paid for (buying video encoder software is like buying an MPEG license included with software). FFmpeg encodes for free because it is classed as an experimental tool. For in-browser recording to H264/MP4 you need to use either Chrome or Safari. Chrome also has the webCodecs API which encodes H264. Final solution is to find a Javascript based H264 encoder then encode your own MP4 from the screenshare pixels etc.